# VMware esxi host partedUtil sector bit and block size?

Tags: vmware-esxi, partition, block

Alright, things i did are: studying https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1036609 and https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2004299 , and also googled some other information about the "partedUtil" in ESXi.

I encountered doubts when utilizing partedUtil commandlines to configure partitions in ESXi 7.0 host but I failed to find proper answer for my own doubts.

According to figure below,

[image]

can anyone please tell me what is the measuring unit(is it kb?) of 16987000 and 17092000? (i know they are the "sector start" and "sector end", respectively.)

additionally, how do i know the measuring unit(mb?) of block size for specific partition(such as VMFS Datastore or Linux Swap, for example) when configuring with partedUtil in ESXi??

The last question is: do I need to multiply "block size" by "space I need" as the space(between start sector and end sector) for the partition I need? or maybe the space between start and end sector is quite simple to calculate which does not need to take "block size" into consideration?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Just to satisfy my own curiosity, why are you doing this, what is it that you're trying to achive?

Comment: it's my server in company's lab environment before getting into production use. I might need to set partitions such as scratch & coredumps to other devices in the future therefore i would like to ensure that the configuration details are correct...thank you!